# Simple Haskell Instance Question

Tags: haskell

I'm trying different data structures for implementing Prim's algorithm. So I made a class to abstract what I want to do:

```
class VertexContainer a where
  contains :: a -> Vertex -> Bool
  insert :: a -> WeightedEdge -> a
  numVertices :: a -> Int
```

Now I want to use a heap (from `Data.Heap`) as my vertex container. But I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax. As you can see from the `insert` declaration, the container can only hold `WeightedEdge`s, which are a data type. So I tried:

```
instance VertexContainer (Heap MinPolicy WeightedEdge) where
  contains _ _ = True
```

It tells me it's an illegal type synonym. I've tried various other permutations, and none of them seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the entire error message you'll find that it tells you how to be able to use a type synonym in an instance declaration, namely by using the language extension TypeSynonymInstances.  E.g., you can pass -XTypeSynonymInstances on the command line.

Comment: Sorry, should've explained the error more. I actually did pass this in, and the full error message that I got is "Illegal type synonym family application in instance:"

Comment: Can you declare the instance on HeapT rather than the synonym Heap? Scanning the source the associated type `Prio` is possibly doing something "unusual".

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by wrapping this into a newtype. Considered ugly. I guess you have to wait for one of the Haskell gurus to answer this.